# C5 collection library - serialization problem over WCF

Tags: wcf, serialization, c5

I am trying to send a TreeDictionary from the [C5 collection library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C5_Generic_Collection_Library_for_C_Sharp_and_CLI) over WCF. It gets to the recipient OK (I had to add a lot of KnownType attributes for what seems to be internal data structures). However, now I am stuck at a point where it fails because it cannot create a default comparer for `C5.KeyValuePair'2[typea,typeb]`.

Is this because the C5 classes inherently cannot go across WCF (and I am lucky to have got this far) or something else?

Answer (score 2):

C5 classes are indeed not designed to go across a serialization boundary.  You have several options.

1. Add a reference to the C5 libraries on your client side.  This is not service oriented and will not work on anything but a .NET client at best.  Not recommended.
2. If possible, convert the dictionary to a regular .NET dictionary and return that.  Your client ought to be able to receive this.

Good luck!